# Will decompiled version of an apk file be allowed by Firbase App Check?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, android-security

Firebase App Check is a wonderful feature. It ensures that only the requests made from **my** app will be allowed. But what will happen if my app is decompiled, the source code is modified a bit, and a new APK is created? Will the requests made from that version be allowed by Firebase App Check?

Comment: I think that won't work because SHA-256 will not match. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps for Firebase App check are as follows:

> Register your apps to use App Check with the SafetyNet provider in the Project Settings > App Check section of the Firebase console. You will need to provide the SHA-256 fingerprint of your app's signing certificate.

And as you can since you would be providing the `SHA-256 fingerprint` from your device, if someone does decompile your app and a new APK is created, the fingerprint won't match unless it is done by someone specifically from your device.

I think you will be fine in most cases. You can read more here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

Comment: It can still be faked, it just requires more work.  If someone is willing to go to the trouble of reverse engineering it, they can find the value that Firebase is sending as the fingerprint in your real version, and alter the Firebase client libraries to send that in all cases instead.  You can never fully trust client data.

Comment: But can they prevent the original apps (using the original SHA-256 fingerprint) from connecting to Firebase?